# How to reuse Flutter InputDecoration and pass in hintText

Tags: flutter, input

New to Flutter Development but using a Constant Dart area to re-use same InputDecoration on many Forms -- but would like to use Hint Text that follows the form calling the InputDecoration defined in Constant.

What is the best way to do this?

This is the Create New Member page that is being called:

New Member App Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shmc_memberapp/models/data/members.dart';
import 'package:shmc_memberapp/shared/constants.dart';

class CreateMembers extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateMembers({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateMembers> createState() => _SHMCMembersState();
}

class _SHMCMembersState extends State<CreateMembers> {
  final controllerRoadName = TextEditingController();
  final controllerFullName = TextEditingController();
  final controllerChapter = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Create New Member"),
          titleTextStyle:
              const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138),
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
              controller: controllerRoadName,
              decoration: textInputDecoration,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: controllerFullName,
              decoration: textInputDecoration,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: controllerChapter,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hintText: 'Chapter ID',
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  )),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: const Text('Create'),
                onPressed: () {
                  final memberData = MemberData(
                    roadName: controllerRoadName.text,
                    fullName: controllerFullName.text,
                    chapterID: int.parse(controllerChapter.text),
                  );
                  createMember(memberData);
                })
          ],
        ),
      );
}

Future createMember(MemberData memberData) async {
  //Reference to Firebase DB and Collection
  final docMember = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shmc_members').doc();
  memberData.id = docMember.id;

  final json = memberData.toJson();
  //Create Document and Write into Firebase DB
  await docMember.set(json);
}
```

This is the constant.dart file that hosts the textInputDecoration code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final textInputDecoration = InputDecoration(
  hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  filled: true,
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5)),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138)),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
);
```

Let me know if there is a better way of doing this in Flutter/Dart.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try these couple of ways:

Set the `InputDecoration` at the theme or extend the class and pass a parameter in it's constructor.

##### Setting it at the theme:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 1.5,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Then use it like this

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Chapter ID'    
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
),
```

##### Extending the class and passing a parameter in the constructor:

```dart
class MyInputDeco extends InputDecoration {
  final String hint;

  const MyInputDeco({required this.hint});

  @override
  String? get hintText => hint;

  @override
  TextStyle? get hintStyle =>
      const TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.blueGrey);

  @override
  InputBorder? get border => OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
      );

  @override
  InputBorder? get focusedBorder => OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 55, 138)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      );

  @override
  Color? get fillColor => Colors.white;

  @override
  bool? get filled => true;
}
```

Then use it this way:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: MyInputDeco(
    hint: 'Chapter ID'    
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
),
```

Comment: Awesome and Thank you for quick reply.  "Older" guy so newer coding has been cool and great learning new ways!  I tried both approaches and ended up with Extending the class so I can move files across apps.  Thanks again!